# Canny Edge Detection and LoG difference

Tags: image-processing

What is the difference between Canny Edge Detector and LoG(Laplace of Gaussian) in Diagital Image Processing ?? I am totally new to Digital Image Processing .. I would be thankful if someone could tell me the difference . Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Canny** edge detector is based on the first derivative of the image (Sobel mask convolution in x and y direction). The magnitude of the derivative will look like this:

[image]

You see that with this operation lines can be identified by pixels which have a high value (are white). The canny algorithm will then also apply non-maxima suppresion and line tracing (see Wikipedia).

The **Laplacian of Gaussian** operator however, is based on the second derivative of the image. A response of this operator will look like this:

[image]

The highest response of the LoG operator will be at the center of blob-like structures in images (same size as the LoG kernel). Lines can be identified using the LoG operator not by finding high magnitudes in the image but by inflection points (zero-crossings). You can see that each line is on one side dark and on the other white. Based on the second derivative, it is highly sensitive to noise.

Comment: What is first derivative and second derivative of an image?

Answer (score 1):

Both are algorithms to detect salient features in images. The Canny Edge Detection looks for edges in the input image. The LoG however looks for blobs in the image, it does this by considering the same image on multiple scales (by scaling down the image repeatedly). However, both are algorithms frequently used to detect salient points in images.

For the differences in the actual algorithms you should consult a textbook or Wikipedia.

Computer vision often needs a set of salient points in an image, for example to compare images, detect objects and so on. However, there is no method for salient point detection which will be best in all cases. Both Canny and LoG are approaches to detecting salient points, but which one works better depends upon the situation.